# Problem with Oracle 12 installation

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to install Oracle 12 but at the end of the installation I got this error

> Invalid SID or Service name.
>   Enter valid SID or Service name.
>
> ERROR - RCU-6090 Connection step validation failed.
>   CAUSE - RCU-6090 Skipping main operation: failed to connect to database because database details were missing or invalid.
>   ACTION - RCU-6090 Provide correct database details and try again.

I'm lost and I don't know what to do at the moment.

Comment: What product did you try to install? RCU is used at install time for other products using an existing database, not the database installer.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I'm trying to install an ERP called ORLIWEB (entreprise CEGID) if you know it I have a script that i execute